# Default hash values

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I'd like to have a hash with `params` members with `defaults` default values:

```
var defaults = { item1: "def1", item2: "def2" };
var params = { item2: "param2", item3: "param3" };
var result = // some clever code here...
console.log(result); // { item1: "def1", item2: "param2", item3: "param3" };
```

The most clever code I can figure out is to iterate `defaults` members and add them into `params` if they are missing there. I wonder if there is some native solution instead of writing own code? Prototyping seems promising, but it only works with functional objects, which I don't want here. Any thoughts?

Comment: This functionality is provided in various Javascript libraries, such as jQuery and Underscore.js. It's often called `extend`.

Comment: True, but it is very easy to write own one-line code. I wonder if there is some native solution?

Comment: The fact that (a) those libraries provide it and (b) don't use a native solution in their implementations strongly suggests to me that there isn't.

Comment: I hope some SO users are more clever than framework writers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested: after almost two years, I guess the clever code mentioned in the question would be

```
__proto__: Object.create(defaults)
```

See the example:

```
var defaults = { item1: "def1", item2: "def2" };
var params = { item2: "param2", item3: "param3",
  __proto__: Object.create(defaults) };

for(var i in params) console.log(i,params[i]);
// item2 param2
// item3 param3
// item1 def1
```

Just keep in mind that the `__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), however well supported unlike the `setPrototypeOf()` method suggested by the link. Let's see what the future will be.